# Countries visited on DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

When applying for a B1/B2 US visa one needs to fill out the form [DS-160](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/). At some point this form ask "Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five years?". When answering yes, you have to "Provide a List of Countries/Regions Visited"

[image: DS-160 Visited countries]

Is it silently understood that those are the countries visited in the last five years, or does one need to provide all countries visited ever?

Comment: Many people already struggle with those visited in the last 5 years, as there are too many or they have lost the details. I think most regulars here can not answer for all they have been with some detail.

Comment: @Willeke in that way countries visited ever is easier to answer correctly because you don't have to think when you visited the country for the last time.

Comment: I do not think they mind you entering one you visited more than 5 years back, but the hard thing on most of those Q is when they ask for visiting details.

Comment: @Willeke They ask for the last five visits to the US with details. That was already hard enough. To do that for all countries is impossible.

Comment: This is why you keep a Google Sheet with all your travels...

Comment: what if someone visited the country after filing the DS160?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the travel.state.gov [FAQ](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html)

> Travel itinerary, if you have already made travel arrangements. Dates
>   of your last five visits or trips to the United States, if you have
>   previously travelled to the United States. You may also be asked for
>   your international travel history for the past five years.

Comment: Yes. That last sentence removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

From an American English common usage point of view, that question is intended to mean list the countries visited in the last five years.

While granted for people who are used to other variations of English this might not be clear, the US Government tends to write out questions and information as if they were speaking with the average American not someone for which English is a second or third language.

Comment: No, the problem is not the language, but rather that I'm a mathematician. I've been trained to make no assumptions unless I can prove them. I would have the same question if it was written in my first language.